# MVC app redirecting to domain name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I have inherited an MVC app which seems to not want to start properly.

When I run the app it initially goes to http://localhost:63744 but then immediately 301 redirects to http://www.thecompanydomainname.com.

I can't seem to find what is causing the redirect I have looked in the home controller and it seems to have an index action but before it gets there the redirect is happening. I should also mention that this mvc site is partly using Umbraco.

I realise that this is impossible to diagnose without having access to the project but I just wondered if anyone have any ideas as to why this might be redirecting and where I should look for the redirecting code?

Many thanks,
Kiran

Comment: Check the code in the RouteConfig.cs file. Its located in the App_Start folder. Without knowing your project, I would start here.

Comment: @CodePull I've solved this problem now. It seems that they were using some complex url rewrite rules. Once the first permanent redirect happened the browser would cache that and keep redirecting afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was being stupid. The browser had cached the first 301 (perm redirect) and from that point on simply redirected the request before it got to the application.

I solved (in chrome) this by going to chrome://net-internals. On the right of the top red status bar, click on the down arrow ▼ to open the drop-down menu, and under the "Tools" group, choose "Clear cache".